# JOIN formula in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to use the JOIN formula in Google Spreadsheets to transform all values in one column into a list, with `,` around each value.

Has anyone used this formula before? The only information I can find is the Google documentation—which describes it as `=JOIN( delim, array_1, ...)`—however, I don't understand what `delim` and `array_1` refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Delim means delimiter

array_1 means the cells you want to use.

```
=join(",",B1:B4)
```

Will put a comma between each value from cells b1 to b4. The result appears in the cell where you put the formula.

Note: the cells must be in the form as 1xN or Nx1 array. In other words all in the same row, or all in the same column.